# How define unquote literal and quote literal by ANTLR3?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I need to match a parameter which either unquote literal or double quote literal. The following is my code, it can not correctly match.

```
DOUBLE_QUOTE: '\"';

fragment
SP         : ' '+;

UnquotedString
     :  
     ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"'|' '|'\t') )*
     ;

QuotedLiteral
    :
    DOUBLE_QUOTE (SP UnquotedString)* DOUBLE_QUOTE
    ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
     |   UNICODE_ESC
     |   OCTAL_ESC
     ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   
    '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;

Parameter
    :
     UnquotedString | QuotedLiteral
    ;

WS  :  ('\r'|'\t'|'\n'|' ') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

For example, when i input **para1 OPERATOR "para2"**, the *Parameter* rule  could be matched **para1** and **"para2"**.

Answer (score 0):

```
QuotedLiteral
:
DOUBLE_QUOTE (SP UnquotedString)* DOUBLE_QUOTE
;
```

- this means that `QuotedLiteral` can either match `""`, or there must be whitespace after the beginning quote. That's probably not what you intended.